# Is there a better implementation for this async loop in JS?

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing a node.js script that uses Playwright to send different messages at a set interval in a browser. I'm running into an issue with an asynchronous part of the script.

I initially had it set up in this way

```
async start() {
  this.interval = setInterval(async () => {
    await sendMessages(this.messages);
  }, 1000);
}
```

I'm pretty sure the `await` keyword does nothing here and just executes the next iteration after 1000 ms regardless of whether `sendMessages` is finished executing or not. This was resulting in messages being double sent when they hit their interval requirement for sending again.

This code works, and is the subject of my question:

```
async start() {
  while (!this.stopFlag) {
    await sendMessages(this.messages);
    await timeout(1000);
  }
}
```

`timeout` is a simple function that resolves a Promise after a `setTimeout` call. However, this seems kind of hacky and I don't really like this way of implementation. Does anyone have a more clever way to execute something like this?

Here are some more code details:

Messenger.js

```
import Message from './Message.js'
import { timeout } from './Timeout.js'
export default class Messenger {
  constructor(messages, page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.messages = messages.map((msg) => new Message(msg));
    this.stopFlag = false;
  }

  async start() {
    while (!this.stopFlag) {
      await this.sendMessages();
      await timeout(1000);
    }
  }

  async sendMessages() {
    for (const message of this.messages) {
      if (message.shouldSend()) {
        await message.send(this.page);
      }
    }
  }

  stop() {
    this.stopFlag = true;
  }
}
```

Message.js

```
export default class Message {
  constructor(message) {
    this.text = message.text;
    this.timing = message.timing;
    this.lastSent = null;
  }

  async send(page) {
    logMessage(`Sending message "${this.text}" in channel.`);
    await playwrightFunctionToSendMessage();
    this.lastSent = new Date();
  }

  shouldSend() {
    // returns a boolean based on this.timing and this.lastSent 
  }
}
```

Comment: How is that while loop not locking up your browser

Comment: What do most people do? They just use the timeout to recall the function.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the solution with `setInterval` starts sending a new batch of message after (roughly) 1000ms, regardless, whether the previous batch has finished or not. Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve, your second approach may be fine. Ie it sends a bunch of messages. Once all messages are sent it (asynchronously) waits a second and then starts the next bunch.

Comment: @epascarello This is a node.js script that uses playwright to manipulate a headless browser. The while loop is the only execution in the script.

Comment: Most people would just code it like `async start() {
    if(this.stopFlag) return; 
      await this.sendMessages();
      setTimeout(()=>start(),1000);
    }
  }`

Comment: Define 'better' and 'clever' in objective, measurable terms. Currently, answers will be opinions of their authors as to what they believe is better or more clever.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I understand your grievance with the wording of my question. I am just looking for opinions on how others would implement this function as I was hitting a wall.

Comment: @epascarello I like that implementation a lot more than mine, thank you for the input!

Comment: Opinion-based questions do not follow the guidelines for StackOverflow. It's not a grievance with wording. It's a guideline for this site and could get your question flagged and possibly removed. I'm curious... are you ever resettings the `stopFlag` back to `false` and restarting the interval? I may be just be overlooking the code...

Comment: @daddygames I worded my response/question poorly, I'm just looking for a different implementation that doesn't involve awaiting inside a `while` loop. And no, currently `stopFlag` gets set to true on an instance of Messenger when the SIGINT event is caught by the node process.

Comment: Opinions about how others would implement this function is off topic for Stack Overflow. If you want your code reviewed, then you might want to draft a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) following their guidelines.

Comment: Your current while-loop looks fine. You could optimise `sendMessages` unless you send the messages in sequence on purpose. Sending them in parallel would finish sending the batch a lot faster. `await Promise.all(this.messages.filter(message => shouldSend()).map(message => message.send(this.page)))`

Comment: @3limin4t0r You're right it would be faster in parallel, however, they are sending messages to the same textfield and hitting a send button. So doing them in parallel is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` inside `setInterval` will not work as expected and will keep adding to the calls to the queue and move on.

```
   this.interval = setInterval(async () => {
    await sendMessages(this.messages); // will not be async as expected
  }, 1000);
```

> if there is a possibility that your logic could take longer to execute
> than the interval time, it is recommended that you recursively call a
> named function using setTimeout(). For example, if using setInterval()
> to poll a remote server every 5 seconds, network latency, an
> unresponsive server, and a host of other issues could prevent the
> request from completing in its allotted time. As such, you may find
> yourself with queued up XHR requests that won't necessarily return in
> order.

Challenge is if you need long-running processes to execute at set times and need a result before the next execution time. Obviously, if it takes longer than the interval to process then you will need a more advanced way to keep track of batches and or reduce the workload.

But if you simply want a way to wait until completion before executing the process again after a delay, you could do:

```js
function sendMessages() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.info('done sending');

      return resolve();
    }, 2000);
  })
}

let stopFlag = false;

async function process() {
  if (stopFlag) {
    console.info('stopping');
  } else {
    // wait till complete and set a new timeout
    await sendMessages();
    setTimeout(() => process(), 1000);
  }
}

process();

// trigger a stop
setTimeout(() => {
  stopFlag = true;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: `async start() { if (this.stopFlag) return; await this.sendMessages(); setTimeout(await this.start.bind(this), 1000); }` I had to bind the start function to this to fix the scope inside the setTimeout, but it works great. Thanks so much Samuel!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `stop` method reassigning `this.stopFlag`, have it clear the interval or timeout.

```
async start() {
    if (this.timeoutId) return; // timeout is already running - don't start another
    const startTimeout = () => {
        this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            this.sendMessages()
                .then(() => {
                    if (this.timeoutId) startTimeout();
                })
                .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part
        }, 1000); // 1 second between finish of last sendMessages and start of next
    };
    startTimeout();
}
stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    this.timeoutId = null;
}
```